# Clear background in RStudio make the plot device doing weird stuff

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm drawing plots to put them in a presentation. But I need a transparent background to fit the colours that I'm using in my presentation. So I decided to use the `par()` function in R like this:

```
dev.off()
par(mfrow=c(1,2),bg = NA)
plot(1:10,main = "This is the first plot yo")
plot(100:1000, main = "What is going on?")
```

Unfortunately, the plot that I have in my device (In RStudio) is looking like this: 
[image]

The thing is that when I export it or use the plot zoom function, it's working. 
[image]

What can cause the device to print the graph badly in RStudio?
Is there another function that I can use so that it doesn't make that weird effect?

Version RStudio: 0.99.902

```
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin13.4.0                
system         x86_64, darwin13.4.0        
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.0                         
svn rev        70573                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce using R-3.2.5-64 (win10-64).

Comment: I'm using RStudio on a Mac

Comment: Does it do the same thing in R itself (no RStudio)?

Comment: Does this problem crop up if you save it directly to a file with `png(file = "myplog.png", bg = "transparent"); *your plot code*; dev.off()`?

Comment: In R it's fine. It's just in the device in RStudio.  exporting to png pdf etc. works fine

Comment: Alright, I'm out. For the record, this bug is not seen in RStudio 0.99.893 with R-3.2.5-64. (You might need to go to [RStudio Support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us) if this is their bug. Perhaps somebody else can verify this bug using R-3.3.0, in case it's just me.)